# Calculus and the intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to understand and prove the fundamental theorem of calculus and I ran into some confusion understanding the intermediate value theorem . several sources online claim that if a function f(x) is continuous on [a,b] let s be a number such that f(a)<s<f(b) then there exists a number k in the open interval (a,b) such that f(k)=s my question is why do we only assume the open interval shouldn't it also include the closed interval [a,b] and also why does s have to be less than both f(a) and f(b)?

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking on "edit" just beneath it. I suggest you do so and add some punctuation to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion “there is some $k\in(a,b)$ such that $f(k)=s$” is stronger than the assertion “there is some $k\in[a,b]$ such that $f(k)=s$”. So, why would we state a weaker statement when we can as easiy prove a stronger one.

And, if you have in mind the statement “if $f(a)\leqslant s\leqslant f(b)$, then there is some $k\in[a,b]$ such that $f(k)=x$”, then that statement is trivial if $s=f(a)$ (just take $k=a$ then) or if $s=f(b)$ (just take $k=b$ then). So, the non-trivial part is when $f(a)<s<f(b)$.

Comment: Ahh thankyou I see how the throrems are stated to highlight the important parts of the statements now

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the statement could (not 'should') refer to the closed interval $[a,b]$ but when $s=f(a)$ or $s=f(b)$ we can obviously take $k=a$ or $k=b$  and this part does not require the continuity assumption at all. Thus, the "interesting" part of the theorem, which does require the continuity assumption, is about an $s$ which is not equal to $f(a)$ or $f(b)$, and consequently, we don't need the endpoints $a,b$ anymore.

For your second question, note that "$s$ has to be less than both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$" is a wrong formulation. What we require of $s$ is that it be an "intermediate value". Think about an intermediate value as some number "intermediate" between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. In other words, if $f(a)<f(b)$ then for $s$ to be between them means $f(a)<s<f(b)$, and if $f(b)>f(a)$ then for $s$ to be between them means $f(b)<s<f(a)$. Note that if $f(a)=f(b)$ the theorem says nothing - you have to assume that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ in order to get proper intermediate values.